# Sum if with multiple criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, sum

I'm looking to do some kind of sum if array formula but I'm little stuck.

I've got a column of data in cells T2:T11 that I want summed.  Each of these cells have two sets of criteria against them in S2:S11 and R2:R11:

*range R2:T11*

1. a - 1 - 22
2. a - 2 - 15
3. a - 3 - 87
4. a - 4 - 82
5. a - 5 - 68
6. b - 1 - 45
7. b - 2 - 46
8. b - 3 - 47
9. b - 4 - 04
10. b - 5 - 51

Now if I just wanted to sum all those that were "b" and "1" for example I'd use a SUMIFS function (answer = 45) however the values I want to sum could be multiples, e.g. "b" and "1, 2 and 4" (answer = 95).  In this example options "a" and "b" are in cells I3:J3 and options 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 are in cells K3:O3.  I've then got x's against those that I want to sum:

*range I3:O4*

1. a - b - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5
2. "" - x - x - x - ""  - x - ""

Once I understand the principle this will be expanded to cover more criteria and the formula will be dragged down a number of rows where there will be x's against different items (sometimes both "a" and "b", sometimes against all, sometimes against none etc.)

I assume I need some kind of SUM(IF(... function as an array but I'm lost.

I managed to make it work for the numbers but not the numbers AND letters together:

`{=SUM(IF(S2:S11=(IF(K4:O4="x",K3:O3)),T2:T11))}`

Anyone able to offer advice?  Obviously I've tried googling the answer but I've not found it - apologies if this has already been answered elsewhere.

Many thanks

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this "array formula"

`=SUM(SUMIFS(T2:T11,R2:R11,TRANSPOSE(IF(I4:J4="x",I3:J3)),S2:S11,IF(K4:O4="x",K3:O3)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

You need `TRANSPOSE` on one of the criteria because one needs to be a "column" and one a "row" - you have two rows so `TRANSPOSE` converts one to a column. This version does not allow any more multi-criteria columns, if you need that you can switch to this version:

`=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(S2:S11,IF(K4:O4="x",K3:O3),0)),IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(R2:R11,IF(I4:J4="x",I3:J3),0)),T2:T11)))`

That's longer but can be extended to use multi-criteria in Q2:Q11, for example

Comment: Absolutely perfect!  Thank you very much for your help.  Seems so obvious now! :P